# Template edits aren't being applied to website

Tags: html, templates

I inherited a website and I need to make changes to the templates. I have access to the template files but they are all greyed out for editing. I am able to edit the grey html in Dreamweaver and Visual Studio Code but the changes don't apply to the website once I upload them. We use Siteground for our web hosting. The edit is the last line of this code - pointing to a different page than previously:

[Find Resources](http://elmo.academyart.edu/find-resources/index.html)
                        
                            [Browse Collections](http://elmo.academyart.edu/find-resources/library_catalog.html)
                            [Course Reserves](http://library.academyart.edu/search/r)
                            [Online Resources](https://libguides.academyart.edu/az/databases)

But the website still goes to the old linked page of the site. The page is here:

https://library.academyart.edu/search/r

and the link is under Find Resources - Online Resources

I tried editing the code within Siteground's editor, tried downloading the files into Dreamweaver and Visual Studio Code and uploading them again and have Googled the issue pretty extensively. I read something about creating a Site Definition in Dreamweaver and also that I need to put all the templates and files that use it in a folder so Dreamweaver can find them and update them - but I'm not sure how to do either of those or if that is good advice. I am a Librarian - not a web developer - and have basic web editing skills. Thanks for any advice anyone has!

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you may be dealing with a caching issue or an incorrect file upload. Ensure you've cleared your browser cache and try uploading the modified files again. If the issue persists, confirm that you're uploading the changes to the correct location on SiteGround, and check if there's any caching mechanism on their end.

Regarding Dreamweaver, creating a Site Definition helps organize files, but it might not directly solve the issue. Ensure you're uploading the modified files to the correct directory on SiteGround, and consider reaching out to SiteGround support for assistance with any server-side caching or configuration that might be affecting the changes.

Comment: Please do not share your personal details here.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your answer. I am uploading the files to the same folder that I downloaded them from. And I did reach out to Siteground and they cleared the server Cache on their end and I have cleared my browser cache. Siteground recommended I post here as they stated this issue was outside of their support area.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).